# Array.map returns undefined array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to map my array of objects and reasign that objects to a new array of objects with another structure.

So i've made the following function in my service

```
  getArticoli(): any {
    let articoli = [];
    return articoli = this.carrello.plu.map(plu => {
      const varianti = [];
      if (plu.varianti) {
      plu.varianti.map(variante => varianti.push(new VariantiArticoli(variante.id, variante.stato)));
      }
      articoli.push(new Articoli('PLUREP', plu.id, plu.qta, varianti));
    });
  }
```

The function doesn't returns any error and in debug the articoli is actually populated with all items but when i'm callind that function in my component and printing the result in a console log, i get the array of n objects from the original array but it's body is set to undefined...

So if in debug i have articoli of two objects in console log i will get array of 2 objects set as undefined..

First array of 5 is `console.log(articoli)` set inside the map, the second is the actual call of `getArticoli()`

```
console.log(this.articoli());
```

[image]

Comment: The callback for `.map()` has to return the new value. Yours doesn't return anything -> `undefined`

Comment: Why is there a `articoli.push()` in the `.map()` callback? The content of `articoli` is overwritten afterwards with the result of `.map()` anyway...

Comment: @Andreas i'm doing `articoli.push` as `carrello.plu` has one object structure and i have to trasform it in another one by using some of data in `carrello.plu`.. at this point should i only use `foreach`?

Comment: Don't use just another function... Read the documentation for `.map()` and arrow functions (implicit `return`). If you're not interested in the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool.

Comment: @JavaScript When the arrow function only consists of an expression then there's an [implicit `return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body), but this is not the case here (at least not in the relevant part `this.carrello.plu.map(...)`)

Comment: @Andreas got it, by using `forEach` and returning explicitly `articoli` after doing `forEach` works as expected